# iPhone do not show as opt-ins into Salesforce Marketing Cloud Dashboard

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilepush-ios, sdk

After setting up the app and json file, I can not see the new device as an opt-ins into the MobilePush dashboard.

However, I can see an interesting error into the console that may be related to the problem:

```
[68852:11631717] [foundation] registration response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x280007ec0> { URL: https://mc45qsr3lcwvpvmshx5r9rw6nlyq.device.marketingcloudapis.com/device/v1/registration } { Status Code: 401, Headers {
"Cache-Control" =     (
    "no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store, private"
);
Connection =     (
    "keep-alive"
);
"Content-Length" =     (
    148
);
"Content-Security-Policy" =     (
    "upgrade-insecure-requests"
);
"Content-Type" =     (
    "application/json; charset=utf-8"
);
Date =     (
    "Tue, 07 May 2019 12:15:57 GMT"
);
"Referrer-Policy" =     (
    "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
);
"Strict-Transport-Security" =     (
    "max-age=15552000; preload"
);
Vary =     (
    Origin
);
"Www-Authenticate" =     (
    "Bearer realm=\"mc45qsr3lcwvpvmshx5r9rw6nlyq.device.marketingcloudapis.com\", error=\"invalid_token\""
);
"x-content-type-options" =     (
    nosniff
);
"x-frame-options" =     (
    DENY
);
"x-mashery-error-code" =     (
    "ERR_403_DEVELOPER_INACTIVE"
);
"x-mashery-message-id" =     (
    "147400f3-cd70-4fe3-8362-2d4b0f6176ba"
);
"x-mashery-responder" =     (
    na
);
"x-xss-protection" =     (
    "1; mode=block"
);
} }
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m
line: 674
```

It looks like it is not able to communicate with SFMC.

I already checked 20 times the **MarketingCloudSDKConfiguration.json** values to be sure they are correct.

Comment: Problem probably related to the used SDK. I updated to last (6.2.2) from 6.0.x and now the error is gone.

Comment: Gabriel, you mention using the JSON configuration file, but were you also configuring the SDK with the "Builder" method? If so, you are correct - the latest SDK does address an issue with case sensitivity in access tokens which was introduced in a change in our server gateway.

Comment: Thank you for the update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest SDK does address an issue with case sensitivity in access tokens which was introduced in a change in our server gateway. This affected the iOS configuration "Builder" usage and was addressed in our 6.2.0 release.

https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/